# laravel raw sql Insert issue

Tags: laravel, mamp-pro

I am in the process of learning Laravel and have hit on an issue.

I am using PHP Storm with both a MAMP Pro stack and a remote LAMP stack.
I have migrated the tables into both databases without issue. 
If I then run the below the page loads correctly - no errors thrown, but in the MAMP Pro stack, the database is still empty.

```
Route::get('/insert', function (){
    DB::insert('insert into posts(title, body) values(?, ?)', ['PHP with Laravel', 'Laravel is the best thing to happen to PHP']);
 });
```

After some more messing about, I tried a different tack - I manually inserted data into the MAMP Pro database, which works fine. 
I can then use `DB::select` and `DB::update` statements to read and update the record perfectly normally...

I'm at a loss, why can I update and read the table, but not insert a new record?

Answer (score 0):

You should be utilizing `DB::table()` and query chaining the `insert()` method from there.

This is the proper method:

```
DB::table('posts')->insert([
    'title' => 'PHP with Laravel',
    'body' => 'Laravel is the best thing to happen to PHP'
]);
```

Comment: OK, Im even more confused now - when I run that code, it inserted two new lines into the table, with the data appearing in the "title" column on each line.